# returning data from function in another file

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to make a function that just checks to see if the user has the correct rank and if they don't have a serial in the database.

I'm having trouble returning the values to use in the file though.

index.php

```
$xf_user = $_SESSION['user']['username'];

check_user_serial($xf_user);
check_user_rank($xf_user);

if($has_serial == 0) {
    if($user_rank == 4) {
        generate_serial($xf_user);
    } else {
        header('Location: ../index.php?d=n');
        die();
    }
} else {
    header('Location: ../index.php?d=s');
    die();
}
```

functions.php

```
function check_user_serial($username) {
    global $dbConnect;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM xf_users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
    try {
        $stmt = $dbConnect->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $has_serial = $row['has_serial'];
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }
    return $has_serial;
}

function check_user_rank($username) {
    global $dbConnect;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM xf_users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
    try {
        $stmt = $dbConnect->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $user_rank = $row['user_rank'];
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }
    return $user_rank;
}

function generate_serial($username) {
    global $dbConnect;
    $serial1 = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), -5, 5);
    $serial2 = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), -5, 5);
    $serial3 = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), -5, 5);
    $serial4 = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), -5, 5);
    $serial  = sprintf('%s-%s-%s-%s', $serial1, $serial2, $serial3, $serial4);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM xf_users WHERE serial = '".$serial."'";
    try {
        $stmt = $dbConnect->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        if($result == NULL) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO xf_users (serial, has_serial) VALUES (:serial, :has_serial) WHERE username = '".$username."'";
            $query_params = array(':serial' => $serial, ':has_serial' => '1');
            try {
                $stmt = $dbConnect->prepare($query);
                $stmt->execute($query_params);
            }
            catch(PDOException $ex) {
                die();
            }
        } else {
            die('serial generation has failed. please notify an administrator.');
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }
    return $serial;
}
```

Comment: spend a little more time on explaining the problem please

Comment: @Dagon What more is there to explain... It doesn't give me back any values..

Comment: **it** which it? i see more than a dozen places that could be **it**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xf_user = $_SESSION['user']['username'];

$has_serial = check_user_serial($xf_user);
$user_rank = check_user_rank($xf_user);

if($has_serial == 0) {
    if($user_rank == 4) {
        generate_serial($xf_user);
    } else {
        header('Location: ../index.php?d=n');
        die();
    }
} else {
    header('Location: ../index.php?d=s');
    die();
}
```

Try this, you weren't assigning `$has_serial` and `$user_rank` to anything.

Debug version:

```
$xf_user = $_SESSION['user']['username'];

    $has_serial = check_user_serial($xf_user);
    $user_rank = check_user_rank($xf_user);

    if($has_serial == 0) {
        if($user_rank == 4) {
            echo "generated serial";
            generate_serial($xf_user);
        } else {
            echo "user rank not 4";
            //header('Location: ../index.php?d=n');
            die();
        }
    } else {
        echo "has serial";
        //header('Location: ../index.php?d=s');
        die();
    }
```

Comment: All I get is a blank page now. :P

Comment: Do you have error warning on? Try debugging it with the code I provided and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Yes, I have error warning enabled, and I don't have any errors. It's just a blank page. I checked all of my die() functions and that's not the cause either. Not sure what it is.

Comment: so I guess the error is in generate_serial($xf_user) because it says generated serial then nothing else has loaded. Putting function in the main post

Comment: Okay, the error was I'm not using UPDATE statement. I was using INSERT when it's already a record. =P Thanks guys so much.

Answer (score 1):

there where you call the function you have to add a variable that gets the data what the function will return:

```
$serial = check_user_serial($xf_user);
$rank = check_user_rank($xf_user);
```

Another problem that is see in the function check_user_serial is that there is no initialization for the  $has_serial variable. It is now possible that the function will return a variable that does not exist. It will happen if there are zero rows retrieved from the database.

For example you could add a rule in top of your function to initialize the variable and assign a default value to it:

```
$has_serial = FALSE;
```

I ll try to explain it with a little example:

```
// wrong
function getNumber($assign)
{
    if($assign)
        $number = 5;

    return $number; // will not exist if $assign == FALSE
}
echo getNumber(FALSE); // will throw an error

// right
function getNumber($assign)
{
    //initialization
    $number = 0;

    if($assign)
        $number = 5;

    return $number; // returns 0 or 5 but will never cause an error
}
echo getNumber(FALSE); // no problem :-)
```